# Improving Simulated Annealing based on Measure of Goodness

Tags: artificial-intelligence, searching

can anyone answer this question or direct me to a reference that can help?

> Simulated Annealing returns the current state when the end of the annealing schedule is reached and if the annealing schedule is slow enough. Given that we know the value (measure of goodness) of each state we visit, is there anything smarter we could do?